# How can I reset a developing macOS app(Using UserDefaults and Realm) elegantly?

Tags: macos, cocoa, realm

In iOS developing, we can reset an app by uninstalling&reinstalling it, but in macOS developing, I have to find my app's UserDefaults plist and delete it, and run this line to flush the realm db:

`try! FileManager.default.removeItem(at:Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)`

Is there a more elegant way to do all the things above?
Or just a better way to reset the realm db?

Comment: Your question seems ill defined. Where did you "install" it in the first place? Normally you can just delete an application package (directory) in order to get rid of it. During development that should not be necessary since Xcode does the replacement automatically for you.

Comment: @Patru I want to delete the user data of my app. Or to be more specific, the data in UserDefaults and database.

Comment: @F.Flamel have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12637976/4063602 maybe that helps you in the right direction

Comment: @Patru I'm sorry but I consider this site as a site for developers. There are some problems which can not be described in code. Such as this one. I am using Realm as my app's database and UserDefaults for some user settings. And each time I want to reset my app, I have to find my app's UserDefaults plist file and delete it then run this line to flush realm db:`try! FileManager.default.removeItem(at: Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)`. I want a more elegant way to do all the things above.

Comment: @EricAya I'm so sorry this is my first time asking a question on Stackoverflow, I will open a new one.

Comment: No no no, you should [edit] this one and improve it; no need to create the same one again. :)

Comment: @EricAya Thank you very mush!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind deleting the files yourself they are located in two different locations:

- NSUserDefaults are located in `~/Library/Preferences/your.app.bundle.identifier.plist`
  (see this answer too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12637976/4063602)
- Your Realm file is located at: `~/Library/Application Support/your.app.bundle.identifier/` (see this answer too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38280282/4063602)

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This way to delete realm file is better than flush realm db using the code above.